# unable to access web application deployed on azure container service

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot

I am trying out azure container services with docker swarm as orch. i am an aws guy and completely new to azure and it has been really tough to get it to work so far. 
i followed the azure dashboard to create a container service which created a resource group. i was able to tunnel in to the swarm-master and run docker commands on the swarm-master. the containers launched successfully too but im unable to access the deployed web app. i tried 80 and 8080 ports. i tried pinging the public IP and dns of the swarm-agent, the pings timed out with message `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0` in `aws` similar issues can be resolved by setting inbound security rules but in azure it seemed like they are already set. Can someone please tell me if im missing something.

following is the guide i followed:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wjxpng6jYs

Answer (score 0):

Please try looking at this guide: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jcorioland/2016/04/25/create-a-docker-swarm-cluster-using-azure-container-service/

The service should be available by accessing the service port on the agent's load balancer's public ip.

If it's not running on port 80, you need to open NSG ports manually.

Please offer more details about the steps you've taken exactly if this doesn't unblock you. What container image? Why are you trying both 80 and 8080? Etc.